# How to do image cropping via protractor script

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor -cucumber framework.When i am uploading the images, sometimes its size may be too large.So when i am uploading, some part of the image get cut.so i have a option to crop the image in that site.while clicking on the crop icon, i am navigated to as given in the image here.

[image]

So What will be the protractor code to get full size image here, or What will be the protractor code to get full part of the image  while uploading.Can anyone  help me..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I never did cropping but i found this may help you

```
npm install croppie
```

then

```
$('.my-image').croppie();
```

you can refer [this](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/)